# python launcher for windows: how to set python executable?

Tags: python, windows

I have multiple versions of python 3 installed on my windows 10: i have python 3.4, 3.5 and 3.6. Now I installed anaconda 3 with python 3.6.4, and I want to start it with py launcher.
When I start py.exe it starts python 3.6 from c:\program\ files\python 3.6. 
I'm unable to tell py.exe to run python from d:\anaconda3.
I tried to create py.ini file, I put it in c:\windows, c:\users\germano\appdata\local, but nothing, py.exe starts only python from c:\program files\pyton 3.6.
Any help?

Comment: The launcher is limited to official python.org installations for the command line `-X[.Y[-32|-64]]` option and "python[X[.Y[-32|-64]]]" virtual commands in shebangs. These versions are enumerated in subkeys of "Software[\WOW6432Node]\Python\PythonCore" in HKLM and HKCU. You can add a virtual command to py.ini for use in shebangs, but not as a command-line option. Of course, in a shebang you could also use the fully-qualified path of the Anancoda "python.exe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#customizing-default-python-versions), you can use the env `PY_PYTHON`, to set the default version of Python.

And with respect to change the default directory did not find any variable for this.