# clarify python version using "py"

Tags: python

I am using the command in cmd:
`py -3.7.6 -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.audio_helpers`

This does not work. I get a response:

```
Unknown option: -3
usage: C:\Users\Yakuza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.
```

============================

**How to specify version for this to work?**

*Sorry for the stupid question, I'm just tired, but I want to finish*

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13211456/5267751 it should work without that bug fix version.

Comment: Related:[python launcher for windows: how to set python executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326263/python-launcher-for-windows-how-to-set-python-executable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify `3.7.6` using the Python Launcher for Windows it only recognizes the first two *digits*, major.minor. You could use a [shebang line](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#shebang-lines) in the file with the full path. Or specify the path to the version you want - `C:\path\to\pythonV3.7.6\python.exe -m ...`

Comment: I've already figured out how to use "py -3.7" correctly. It was necessary to first install the "3.7" version of python itself xD. But still many thanks for the answer :3